# Runtime error when adding hyperlink to a cell

Tags: excel, vba

Appears inexplicably after executing error-free for months

I keep running into a runtime error 1004 when the below code executes. I have been running the exact same code for months without issue. Today, I added a new worksheet and edited the positions of some controls on a userform and added a few new ones. Both of these actions affected things completely unrelated to the issue, but I mention it because I don't know what else it could possibly be.

The error occurs on the line `.Hyperlinks.Add` and **does not appear to be caused by unexpected values for variables being used.** See the below code snippet for comments regarding the value of these variables. I'm at a loss here, this code has never had an issue but now it magically does, and the variables have the expected values. I'm thinking it has to be something with a sheet setting or workbook setting. I am dealing with protected sheets, although this is nothing new and hasn't caused an issue before. The sheets are protected using `ws.Protect Password:="abcd", UserInterfaceOnly:=True` which should allow VBA to still edit protected sheets without issue.

**Any ideas on what could possibly be causing this problem?**

```
Public Sub Write_Next_LineItem(ByVal rowNum As Integer, ByRef arr1() As Variant, ByVal strHash As String, Optional ByVal IsPartsOrder As Boolean = False)
    Dim startRow As Integer, j As Integer, entryCount As Integer, strFormula As String

    If fastMode = False Then Disable_Slowdowns 'turns off screen updating, Excel events, and switches calculation mode to xlCalculationManual
    startRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overview").Range("rng_ProjectList").Cells(1, 1).Row
    entryCount = 0


    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overview") 

        'Note that "Overview" is in fact a valid sheet name, evident by the value of startRow which was
        'set by referencing the sheet a few lines above


        '<<<<< code here that determines the value of entryCount. At this point, startRow = 14, entryCount = 0


        '***********************THE NEXT LINE IS CAUSING THE ERROR*************************

        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(startRow + entryCount, 2), Address:="", SubAddress:=wsName & "R1C1"


        'the error occurs with the following values in these variables:
        'startrow = 14
        'entrycount = any number (tested with entryCount = 0, 1, 2)
        'wsName = 'Column-Order'!
        'where Column-Order is the name of a worksheet that was just 
        'added programmatically, and is a valid worksheet name (I've triple checked)



        'other code here, but is not executed due to the above error
    End With
End Sub
```

[EDIT]: I've included the code for fastMode below. It's not fastMode causing the issue. As for the comments asking for the code I was editing, like I said it was a userform and a new worksheet, but this isn't being used at all during this error so I'm not going to show that here or this post will become about 4x as long.

```
'In a separate code module:
Public fastMode As Boolean
Public Sub Disable_Slowdowns(Optional ByVal AllowScreenUpdating As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal AllowCalculations As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal AllowEvents As Boolean = False)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    fastMode = True
End Sub
```

[EDIT #2]: Well, with absolutely no change to the code *again*, I opened it up today and for some incredibly aggravating reason it is no longer having this problem. I am thoroughly baffled now. I've been working on this VBA project for the better part of 2 years and I have never experienced anything as erratic and unexplainable as this. I guess I should be happy it's working, but this is going to seriously bug me.

Comment: Looks like you're referencing at least one variable or function outside this procedure (`fastMode`).  Can you provide the code on that?

Comment: You could try to unprotect sheet before making the change. You made changes to the book and code so you may want to share some of the other code that was new as well. The fact that this used to run without any issues here seems completely irrelevant since you have made changes. That is just noise in your question and I would remove it. On the verge of TLDR especially since most of the info is **useless**

Comment: Try checking that the worksheet is still called "Overview" and named range `rng_ProjectList` still refers to the same range you think it does.

Comment: Try using the code to add the hyperlink to a new workbook.

Comment: What's the text of the error message?

Comment: @ChrisB - see above edits for fastMode code. The range is still a valid name because startRow has a value of 14 when hitting the error. This also means the sheet is a valid sheet reference. I've also tried it using other addresses, manually typed in as string literals - same result. I'll see what happens when trying to add to another worksheet

Comment: @TimWilliams "Runtime error 1004 - application-defined or object-defined error" - this is how I know it's not an issue of an uninitialized variable or something.